# In java, how to get / create an object containing a row that I got from php?

Tags: java, android, mysql, database

I made an Android application using [this guide](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm)

In that guide, in the php file, they select "Role", and echo it.
in the Java file, they get it as a String.

My question is: if I would like to have the entire row in my Java file, how do I do this?
I know I could echo all the data in a Json format, but for some reason, I don't like it.

I'm a beginner developer, I know, maybe my entire architecture is wrong.
I'm here to learn.

Comment: _for some reason, I don't like it_ is not a very compelling argument. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @Keppil - you took the paste out of my keyboard, I also absolutely loved that argument. For some reason, the OP doesn't like simple, working solutions. Oh my, why bother with programming then in the first place? :)

Comment: Why do people waste time for writing bad comments? I don't like it because it's the only idea that I have in mind with my knowledge, and I just feel that it is not a nice, practical, smart way to do it... You don't like it that a beginner has the same idea as you, senior?